# How to pop context with FLUTTER go_router?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, navigation, gorouter

How do I go back to the previous screen with flutter's go_router? How to pop context?

Currently I am simply adding a new screen to the stack whether I want to go back or go forward.

```
 onTap: (() => context.go("/secondPage"))
```

I have used  `context.pop()` but it throws error saying -

```
_AssertionError ('package:go_router/src/matching.dart': Failed assertion: line 102 pos 9: '_matches.isNotEmpty': You have popped the last page off of the stack, there are no pages left to show)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You pop it using `context.pop()`.

But in order that something will pop out, it should be in the router's stack.

So, the actual question is how to put the route in the router stack.
Go_router has two methods `go` and `push` both will take you to the next screen specified by the parameter.

But, `push` will **always** add (push) a new route to the stack, while `go` will add a new route only if it is specified as a subroute to the previous screen. Otherwise, it will replace the previous route with a new one.

So, using the given example:

either use `push`

```
 onTap: (() => context.push("/secondPage"));
```

or specify `secondPage` as a subroute to `firstPage` and then use `go`

```
GoRoute(
    path: "/firstPage",
    builder: (context, state) => const FirstPage(),
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: "secondPage",
        builder: (context, state) => const SecondPage(),
      ),

    ],
  ),

...

   onTap: (() => context.go("/secondPage"));
```

[Here is the article where I learned all the above](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-navigation-gorouter-go-vs-push/)

Answer (score 18):

You can use context.pop() if your page is rendered via go_router. But if you are using showModalBottomSheet or Dialog class then you should continue to use Navigator.pop(context)

Comment: Okay, that worked. I had to use context.push("/secondPage") to be able to use context.pop(). Thank you